# Method skips return statement

Tags: java, object, unmarshalling

I have an unmarshal method:

```
public static Object unmarshalXmlTo0100(String xmlMsg, String destination, String resource) throws Exception {
    //init unmarshaller
    ByteArrayInputStream input = new ByteArrayInputStream(xmlMsg.getBytes());
    JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(destination);
    Unmarshaller unmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();

    //init schema
    SchemaFactory schemaFactory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
    Schema schema = schemaFactory.newSchema(XmlParser.class.getClassLoader().getResource(resource));
    unmarshaller.setSchema(schema);

    //unmarschal
    Object data = unmarshaller.unmarshal(input);

    //return message
    return data;
 }
```

Now for some reason when I use the following to call the method:

```
processDataObj = MainXMLParser.unmarshalXmlTo0100(processData, "cp.jaxb.planningBericht.classes", "source/xml/cp_md_format_planningBericht.xsd");
```

Everything goes fine.

But when I use the following:

```
processDataObj = MainXMLParser.unmarshalXmlTo0100(processData, "cp.jaxb.beschikbaarheidBericht.classes", "source/xml/cp_md_format_beschikbaarheidBericht.xsd");
```

The unmarshaller returns nothing, but it does continue with running, so the proccesDataObj is empty...

I have no clue what is going wrong...

Comment: Did you debug the code to see in which line it goes wrong?

Comment: Yes, its seems to go wrong when creating the Object data

Comment: Could you perhaps post the resources, or some way to access them? Your code seems to be ok, so it is probably a problem with the input.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/Wa7jUMkV is the XSD http://pastebin.com/jhVkHaNv is the xml msg

Comment: I checked the XML against the schema, and it doesn't match. Btw, in this example your XML misses the last >

Comment: (checked with http://www.utilities-online.info/xsdvalidation/)

Comment: Yeah I noticed just now, seems that the XSD in the source not change when I make a change to the ones in JAXB bindings. I'll have to manually copy the XSD to the used package. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure the other XSD file is present in mentioned location? Are you positive, that this XSD scheme is actually "correct" (e.g. has expected name spaces and other types)?